# PHP how delete array in array?

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array like this:

```
$_SESSION = Array ( 
        [chose_image] => Array (
             [56915e7c48177e251e1c16f1] => Array (
                [title] => title1
                [author] => author1 
                [watermark] => watermark1 
                [file_name] => name1.jpg 
                [visible] => 1 
                [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 56915e7c48177e251e1c16f1 )
             ) 
            [56915dad48177ee21d1c16f0] => Array (
                [title] => title2
                [author] => author2
                [watermark] => watermark2
                [file_name] => name2.jpg
                [visible] => 1
                [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 56915dad48177ee21d1c16f0 )
            )
        )
    )
```

And I would like to delete the whole array:

```
Array (
             [56915e7c48177e251e1c16f1] => Array (
                [title] => title1
                [author] => author1 
                [watermark] => watermark1 
                [file_name] => name1.jpg 
                [visible] => 1 
                [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 56915e7c48177e251e1c16f1 )
```

by using the [$id]. It is very important to do this by $id, because the array is dynamically filling by users. Is it possible?

Comment: That's where `unset()` is made for

Comment: Unset will remove thw index permently

Comment: Two ways.. one is unset second is make a new array and ignore this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: `unset($_SESSION['chose_image'][$id]);` or `$_SESSION['chose_image'][$id] = null;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
$sample_id = "56915e7c48177e251e1c16f1"; // for example
$_SESSION['chose_image'] = array_filter($_SESSION['chose_image'], function($v) use($sample_id){
    return $v["_id"]->$id != $sample_id; // Though $id is bad name for object property
});
```